# How to force repaint of a glass pane?

Tags: java, swing, glasspane

I have a Swing app with a glass pane over a map.

It paints dots at certain positions. When I click somewhere on the map, and the glass pane receives the message `CONTROLLER_NEW_POLYGON_MARK` I 
want do display an additional dot at the position specified in the event data (see `MyGlassPane.propertyChange`).

The glass pane class is called `MyGlassPane`. Using the debugger I validated that `addPointToMark` is actually called in `propertyChange`.

But no additional dots appear on the screen.

How can I change the code so that `PointSetMarkingGlassPane.paintComponent` is called whenever an event (`IEventBus.CONTROLLER_NEW_POLYGON_MARK`) is fired?

```
public class PointSetMarkingGlassPane extends JComponent implements IGlassPane {
    private final ILatLongToScreenCoordinatesConverter latLongToScreenCoordinatesConverter;
    private final List<Point.Double> pointsToMark = new LinkedList<Point.Double>();

    public PointSetMarkingGlassPane(final ILatLongToScreenCoordinatesConverter aConverter) {
        this.latLongToScreenCoordinatesConverter = aConverter;
    }

    protected void addPointToMark(final Point.Double aPoint)
    {
        if (aPoint != null)
        {
            pointsToMark.add(aPoint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics aGraphics) {
        for (final Point.Double pointToMark : pointsToMark)
        {
            final Point positionInScreenCoords = latLongToScreenCoordinatesConverter.getScreenCoordinates(pointToMark);
            drawCircle(aGraphics, positionInScreenCoords, Color.red);
        }
    }

    private void drawCircle(Graphics g, Point point, Color color) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, 10, 10);
    }

}

public class MyGlassPane extends PointSetMarkingGlassPane implements PropertyChangeListener {
    public MyGlassPane(ILatLongToScreenCoordinatesConverter aConverter) {
        super(aConverter);

        addPointToMark(DemoGlassPane.ARTYOM);
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (IEventBus.CONTROLLER_NEW_POLYGON_MARK.equals(evt.getPropertyName()))
        {
            addPointToMark((Point.Double)evt.getNewValue());
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if is work in JFrame the isn't reason why not in the case when is placed in GlassPane or JViewport, be sure that without an SSCCE is everything here about guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think `invalidate()` only flags your component to check sizes and layout. You should call `repaint()` to repaint your pane.

Also I am wondering why you use propertyChangeListener for mouse clicks. I would prefer just simple mouse listener + MouseAdapter and MouseEvent x, y, buttons state.

Comment: @mKorbel No, you should not call `super.paintComponent()` explicitly. painting component should take place in event thread, because swing is not thread safe.

Comment: alone repaint() only commulating painting without super.paintComponent()

Comment: @mKorbel can you extend that comment? what you mean by 'commulating painitng'? and `without super.paintComponent()`?

Comment: super.paintComponent() remove all previous painting, for more info to see posts tagged by java + swing + paintComponent (here), especially posts by camickr, HFOE, MadProgrammer, but there is another issue in OPs code (AFAIK) because PropertyChangeListener will notify interal methods implemented in APIs, then there is 2nd. point that isn't neccessary to call for repaint(), but nobody knows without an SSCCE, endless song, blood_song that we are singing here :-)

Comment: @mKorbel I still think that you are not right. Of course, @Dmitri Pisarenko should add `super.paintComponent(aGraphics)` due to Swing  programming practices, **but in `paintComponent` method and not where `invalidate();` currently is**. Adding `super.paintComponent()` doesn't help to resolve this question issue.

Answer (score 0):

`invalidate()` probably won't help you, as it flags a component for layout changes, not painting changes.  Why not call `repaint()` instead?

For better performance, you could call the `repaint` method which takes a Rectangle (or four ints representing a rectangle), so that only the newly added point is repainted;  I would suggest changing the return type of `addPointToMark` from void to java.awt.Point, and have it return the result of `latLongToScreenCoordinatesConverter.getScreenCoordinates`, so MyGlassPane can derive a rectangle from that Point which can then be passed to a repaint method.

Comment: or super.paintComponent()

Comment: As I understand it, super.paintComponent is only required of subclasses of components with UI delegates, and is not strictly required of direct subclasses of JComponent.  I've never actually put that to the test, though.

Comment: alone repaint() only commulating painting without super.paintComponent(),